# C++ reference and non reference return of class object- why output same?

Tags: c++

consider the following code:

```
class Test  
{  
    public:  
    int data;

    Test() { data = 9; }

    Test myfunction ();
    void print() { cout << data<<endl; }
};  

Test m;
Test Test::myfunction ()
{
    return m;
};    


int main()
{   
    Test b;
    Test a;
    b=a.myfunction();
    b.print();

    return 0;
}
```

even if i **only replace the function** with the following, the output remains the same ( **i do not change anything inside the main section**). why is that so?

```
class Test  
{  
    public:  
    int data;

    Test() { data = 9; }

    Test& myfunction ();
    void print() { cout << data<<endl; }
};  

Test m;

// function replaced and now it has reference return
Test& Test::myfunction ()
{
    return m; 
};   


int main()
{   
    Test b;
    Test a;
    b=a.myfunction();
    b.print();

    return 0;
}
```

what is the **difference between both the cases.?**
i have not worked much with references so please explain in detail.

Both compiles fine with output in each case as:
9

Comment: Why would it be any different? Returning by reference just returns a "reference" to the object, so both `b` and `m` "point" to the same object. Returning by value copies the object and puts it in `b`.

Comment: I removed C tag because C has neither references nor classes.

Comment: @Borgleader if i use the following code then why the ouput is same in following two cases:

`    
    class Test  
    {  
        public:  
        int data;

        Test() { data = 9; }
        
     Test& myfunction ();
        void print() { cout << data<<endl; }
    };  
    
    Test m;
    Test& Test::myfunction ()
    {
        return m;
    };    

    
    int main()
    {   
        Test b;
        Test a;
        b=a.myfunction();
        b.print();
        m.data=7;
        b.print();

        return 0;
    }
`
output is :
9
9// why not 7?

Comment: @user3249833 the code you posted in the question doesn't have a line `m.data = 7;` - if you could show the code from your comment in the question maybe people will take another look (it is really hard to read code in comments...)

Answer (score 2):

In the first snippet you return a copy of the global instance `m`. In your case the compiler generates a *trivial copy constructor*, that will copy your member `data`. Also, you get a *trivial trivial copy assignment operator* generated which copies the result to `b`, also copying your member `data` automatically.

The second version returns a reference to the global instance `m`. From this point it works the same as the first case: result is being assigned to `b`. It's just one copy operation of `Test` less.

Answer (score 1):

All the objects you created use the default constructor, which assigns data=9. There is no code where you change `data` to anything else. So you wouldn't see anything but `9`

In the first case, when you return by value, the object is copy constructed. Since you did not provide an explicit copy constructor, `data` is copied as is.

Add this to see different output,

```
Test(const Test& lhs){ data = 22; }
```

What is the output you expect to see? Or which part of reference is confusing?

Comment: imo this should be a comment.

Comment: Added as an answer coz I explained why he sees same output. And in which case he'll see a different output.